# Синхронизация кода и бд

Tags: yii2, git, синхронизация

Как происходит процесс синхронизации кода и архитектуры БД на локале и удаленном сервере средствами фреймворка YII2 и Git

Comment: слишком общий вопрос, переформулируйте его более конкретно

Comment: GIT для синхронизации и нужен. Локально работаете, потом push ветки мастер и синхронизировалось... YII2 это только PHP фреймворк. Изменения в БД можете писать в update.sql, добавляя в конец новые команды, либо копайте в сторону миграций.